# Deserialize JSON response coming from SkyDrive to a Custom Class

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, onedrive

I want to deserialize the JSON response coming from LiveConnectClient.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files")  to a custom class to find out if a specific folder is there on the skydrive root. I got the json result from the skydrive and used json2csharp.com to get the class structure. Then i used Json.net's DeserializeObject method to deserialize the json to the class structure. But it throws an Exception during execution. I got the desired result without converting the json result. But i want to know what went wrong and how to convert it to my custom class. The code is given below

```
private async void btnFldrStruct_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LiveOperationResult opResult = await client.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files");
        dynamic skyResult = opResult.Result;
        var fileList = skyResult.data;
        SkyDrive skydrive = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SkyDrive>(fileList);
        ...
    }
```

Exception is thrown at

```
SkyDrive skydrive = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SkyDrive>(fileList);
```

The exception is

```
 Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
```

Message
    The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)'

has some invalid arguments

Stack Trace

```
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
at SkyDriveTestApp.MainPage.<btnFldrStruct_Click>d__26.MoveNext()
```

The classes from json2csharp

```
public class From
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class SharedWith
{
    public string access { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string parent_id { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public string upload_location { get; set; }
    public int comments_count { get; set; }
    public bool comments_enabled { get; set; }
    public bool is_embeddable { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public SharedWith shared_with { get; set; }
    public string created_time { get; set; }
    public string updated_time { get; set; }
    public string client_updated_time { get; set; }
    public int? tags_count { get; set; }
    public bool? tags_enabled { get; set; }
    public string picture { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public List<Image> images { get; set; }
    public string when_taken { get; set; }
    public int? height { get; set; }
    public int? width { get; set; }
    public object location { get; set; }
    public object camera_make { get; set; }
    public object camera_model { get; set; }
    public int? focal_ratio { get; set; }
    public int? focal_length { get; set; }
    public int? exposure_numerator { get; set; }
    public int? exposure_denominator { get; set; }
}

public class SkyDrive
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

can someone tell me what is wrong here and how to fix it. Thank you

Comment: Is filelist of type string?

Comment: "Message The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)'

has some invalid arguments" must mean 'filelist' is not of the expected type... How we love var...

Comment: fileList is not a string. I used var because i don't know what is the type of the result coming. i see that because fileList is not a string  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SkyDrive>(fileList); throws the exception. how can i get the json string then? skyResult is a dynamic type. how can i get the json string out of it?

Comment: Have you tried the ToString()? Try to check the properties of fileList from the debugger.

Comment: @ChrisK - using ToString() on skyResult.data lead to this exception
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
Message: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: What is the type of skyResult at runtime?